# How do NAT or proxy react to incoming TCP SYN packet?

Tags: networking, tcp, proxy, nat

In some messaging systems, two messaging clients send/receive packets directly from each other in chatting or voice call. I think the basic mechanism is (TCP for example): these client programs open a listening TCP socket and tell the messaging/coordinating server their IP/PORT pair. Then the client programs retrieve IP/PORT of the other side from the messaging/coordinating server. And one of them(let's say A) then initiates a TCP with the other one(let's say B) with the retrieved IP/PORT pair of B.

When the passive client B(who waits for the TCP SYN packet) is not behind NAT or a proxy, this is fine. But if B is behind a NAT or a proxy, then the IP/PORT pair is actually the public network interface of the NAT or the proxy.

So my question is, when a NAT or proxy receives a TCP SYN, what is its reaction? How do they relay the TCP SYN to the corresponding host/process behind it?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your initial assumption is correct. More likely they both open active connections to a server and the server routes the data between them. It's a lot simpler and the problems you describe disappear.

Answer (score 0):

This question was obviously asked long time ago but still...

Chat and voice/video call are usually handled quite differently. In case of chat, you'd probably use XMPP protocol where both ends would connect to the server and exchange data through it. XMPP resides on TCP on layer-4 as the reliability is higher priority than latency in this case. Since the clients are the ones that open and maintain the connection, you won't have NAT issues in this case.

On the other hand, voice/video calls are a bit more complex so you'd typically have:

- signaling part, where you negotiate the network (IP address and port) and codec details necessary to setup the call (known as SDP - Session Description Protocol)
- media part, where you're effectively exchange the voice/video content between 2 call-parties.

Signaling usually goes over TCP using some higher-layer protocols like SIP (Session Initiation Protocol). This communication would go through the server. Media goes over UDP using higher-layer protocols like RTP (Real-time Transport Protocol) and this part of communication typically goes peer-to-peer. Single UDP port can be used to both transmit and receive the traffic for one voice/video channel. Additionally, you'll probably want to have the info about call quality while the call is in place, so you could e.g. decrease the bandwidth used in order to avoid/reduce the packet loss. For that purpose, you'd use protocol like RTCP (Real-time Transport Control Protocol). In this case, NAT traversal is crucial! Since neither clients know their public IP addresses, you need a server ourside of your internal network (on public internet) that could tell 'how you're seen from the outside' i.e. behind the NAT. In e.g. WebRTC world this server is knows ICE. After the peer finds out how it's visible from the internet, it'll put that info inside SDP piece of the signaling message so the other end could reach it through the internet. Have in mind that the router that performs NAT might also require some additional settings to keep the track of voice/video UDP ports in use (to NAT-back the traffic from the internet to you).

Finally, there are other solutions used in these cases but that depends on your setup. If you're writing a software for an end user, then previous explanations would apply. However, if you're writing a software for enterprise market, solutions like additional server (known as EDGE) at the border of your corporate network would be a common approach.

I can write about this for hours but this should be enough for a start... :)